# What's plugin used in Shopify?

Tags: plugins, shopify

Does anyone know what plugin used on this website? https://www.barkbox.com/subscribe

How the flow of the subscription that leads to checkout. Hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think that site is Shopify: https://whatcms.org/?s=www.barkbox.com

Comment: You are 100% correct. Not a Shopify store at all. Custom Rails job...

Comment: Thank you. I thought this is a shopify site.